# pandas updating column values for performace

Tags: python, pandas

What is the recommended way to apply a function to a pandas column for performance.
For example

```py
df["title"]=df["title"].apply(word_tokenize)
```

I'm talking about 20 million rows for example.

There was a thread talking about this, and refering to pandas docs, cant seem to find either

Comment: It depends on the function. If you can vectorise the function, for example concatenation of strings, then it is faster to do something like this: `df['name] = df['first_name] + ' ' + df['surname]`. Otherwise, you have to use `.apply()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over all there is no alternative for **apply()** method. As long as performance is considered it depends on the performance of the function you want to apply on your data. So optimize your function and use **multi-threading**.

Comment: does the df["title"]=df["title"].apply(func) play any role? I remember a thread saying don't update the same entry you are altering. Would df["newTitle"]=df["title"].apply(func) be better?

Comment: @Doitsidis No, it does not matter.